# Can I make wordpress act like stack exchange?

Tags: wordpress

Does anybody know a way to make wordpress act like stack exchange?

1. reader accounts
2. thumbing up and down posts
3. ability to edit posts
4. ability to add or remove keywords
5. SE markdown

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can make it. There might not be exact plugin to fulfill your requirement so you need to customize plugin or need to build custom plugin or theme to fulfill your requirement.

Furthermore, [bbPress](http://bbpress.org/) plugin nearly meets of your requirement (about 50 to 60 % ). You can customize it to enhance other features.